# Rails 4 App on Heroku, Works but Errors in Log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, thin, ruby-on-rails-4

The app appears to be working but I am getting these errors in my log. This issue displays in the log for "/favicon.ico", "/assets/application-34baf7d108c7408a8c110454dc57e8f6.js", and "/assets/application-e6b66fbbea8acd5eddb9fada1fa91c36.css" on each page load.

Additionally, this problem does not happen in development, only on heroku.

And, even though it is saying ruby/1.9.1, I just checked with "heroku run ruby -v" and confirmed I am running "ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]"

```
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-03-12T03:34:50.307770 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 99.104.137.64 at 2013-03-12 03:34:50 +0000
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2013-03-12T03:34:50.322285 #2] FATAL -- : 
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/favicon.ico"):
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-f278deb712b1/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-f278deb712b1/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-f278deb712b1/railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-f278deb712b1/railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-f278deb712b1/activesupport/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-f278deb712b1/activesupport/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-f278deb712b1/activesupport/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-f278deb712b1/railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-f278deb712b1/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-f278deb712b1/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-f278deb712b1/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-f278deb712b1/railties/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `call'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-f278deb712b1/railties/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-f278deb712b1/railties/lib/rails/commands.rb:80:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-f278deb712b1/railties/lib/rails/commands.rb:75:in `tap'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-f278deb712b1/railties/lib/rails/commands.rb:75:in `<top (required)>'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   bin/rails:4:in `require'
2013-03-12T03:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get rid of the error, I did this in my config/enviroments/production.rb

```
-  config.assets.compile = false
+  config.assets.compile = true
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to your solution you can compile the assets locally, then send them up to heroku...

```
$ rake assets:precompile
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m 'compiled assets'
$ git push heroku master
```

I do this as part of a CI step